# How to fetch records in JPA repository using where clause injection?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement, where user should able to search data based on page index and page size . Also user can pass filter and order criteria in sql query format (e.g. filter query **name='abc' and enabled =true**  and order query **name asc, lastname desc**).

How to should I achieve this using and JPA Repository and based on above selection criteria?

Below will be exact request format to search records.

```
{
  "page_index": 1,
  "page_size": 100,
  "search_string": "name = 'abc' and enabled = true",
  "sort_criteria": "name DESC, lastname ASC"
}
```

Comment: Hi, you ask too much and you give out too few info about your project, code and setup. You can read about paging in jpa and spring-data here: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pagination and here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting . Try something based on these and come back with a more robust question sharing some of your code if possible.

Comment: P.S. your `search_string` and `sort_criteria` examples indicate that you should be using `entityManager.createQuery` to construct your query and not relying on `JpaRepository` means of querying (method name and/or `@Query` annotation)

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to help you start:

**Foo Entity** (note I am using lombok for annotations like `@Data`, `@ToString` etc to avoid boilerplate code)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "lastname", unique = true)
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private boolean enabled;
}
```

**CustomFooRepository** Interface containing our custom method for the queries

```
public interface CustomFooRepository {

    List<Foo> customQuery(Integer pageIndex, Integer pageSize, String whereClause, String sorting);
}
```

**CustomFooRepositoryImpl** Implementation of `CustomFooRepository`. Here we inject `EntityManager` to compose our native query as we wish:

```
public class CustomFooRepositoryImpl implements CustomFooRepository {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Foo> customQuery(Integer pageIndex, Integer pageSize, String whereClause, String sorting) {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM foo";
        if (whereClause != null) {
            sql = sql + " WHERE " + whereClause; // prone to SQL Injection beware!!!
        }
        if (sorting != null) {
            sql = sql + " ORDER BY " + sorting; // prone to SQL Injection beware!!!
        }
        Query nativeQuery = em.createNativeQuery(sql, Foo.class);
        nativeQuery.setFirstResult((pageIndex-1) * pageSize);
        nativeQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        return nativeQuery.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Our **FooRepository** which extends both `JpaRepository` and `CustomFooRepository`

```
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long>, CustomFooRepository {
}
```

And finally some test to prove it works:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class FooTests {

    @Autowired
    FooRepository fooRepository;

    @Test
    void testFoo() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            fooRepository.save(new Foo(null, "name" + (i+1), "lastname" + (i+1), i%2==0));
        }

        List<Foo> all = fooRepository.findAll();
        System.out.println("All Foos in DB");
        all.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");


        List<Foo> foos = fooRepository.customQuery(1, 10, "name like '%name%' and enabled = true", "name DESC, lastname ASC");
        System.out.println("First 10 results (page 1 and pageSize 10) of Foos in DB with name like '%name%' and enabled = true and sorted by name DESC, lastname ASC");
        foos.forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}
```

The test's output is:

```
All Foos in DB
Foo(id=1, name=name1, lastname=lastname1, enabled=true)
Foo(id=2, name=name2, lastname=lastname2, enabled=false)
Foo(id=3, name=name3, lastname=lastname3, enabled=true)
Foo(id=4, name=name4, lastname=lastname4, enabled=false)
Foo(id=5, name=name5, lastname=lastname5, enabled=true)
Foo(id=6, name=name6, lastname=lastname6, enabled=false)
Foo(id=7, name=name7, lastname=lastname7, enabled=true)
Foo(id=8, name=name8, lastname=lastname8, enabled=false)
Foo(id=9, name=name9, lastname=lastname9, enabled=true)
Foo(id=10, name=name10, lastname=lastname10, enabled=false)
Foo(id=11, name=name11, lastname=lastname11, enabled=true)
Foo(id=12, name=name12, lastname=lastname12, enabled=false)
Foo(id=13, name=name13, lastname=lastname13, enabled=true)
Foo(id=14, name=name14, lastname=lastname14, enabled=false)
Foo(id=15, name=name15, lastname=lastname15, enabled=true)
Foo(id=16, name=name16, lastname=lastname16, enabled=false)
Foo(id=17, name=name17, lastname=lastname17, enabled=true)
Foo(id=18, name=name18, lastname=lastname18, enabled=false)
Foo(id=19, name=name19, lastname=lastname19, enabled=true)
Foo(id=20, name=name20, lastname=lastname20, enabled=false)
....
Foo(id=90, name=name90, lastname=lastname90, enabled=false)
Foo(id=91, name=name91, lastname=lastname91, enabled=true)
Foo(id=92, name=name92, lastname=lastname92, enabled=false)
Foo(id=93, name=name93, lastname=lastname93, enabled=true)
Foo(id=94, name=name94, lastname=lastname94, enabled=false)
Foo(id=95, name=name95, lastname=lastname95, enabled=true)
Foo(id=96, name=name96, lastname=lastname96, enabled=false)
Foo(id=97, name=name97, lastname=lastname97, enabled=true)
Foo(id=98, name=name98, lastname=lastname98, enabled=false)
Foo(id=99, name=name99, lastname=lastname99, enabled=true)
Foo(id=100, name=name100, lastname=lastname100, enabled=false)
```

And

```
First 10 results (page 1 and pageSize 10) of Foos in DB with name like '%name%' and enabled = true and sorted by name DESC, lastname ASC
Foo(id=99, name=name99, lastname=lastname99, enabled=true)
Foo(id=97, name=name97, lastname=lastname97, enabled=true)
Foo(id=95, name=name95, lastname=lastname95, enabled=true)
Foo(id=93, name=name93, lastname=lastname93, enabled=true)
Foo(id=91, name=name91, lastname=lastname91, enabled=true)
Foo(id=9, name=name9, lastname=lastname9, enabled=true)
Foo(id=89, name=name89, lastname=lastname89, enabled=true)
Foo(id=87, name=name87, lastname=lastname87, enabled=true)
Foo(id=85, name=name85, lastname=lastname85, enabled=true)
Foo(id=83, name=name83, lastname=lastname83, enabled=true)
```

You can pick up this sample code and adapt it to your needs.

**Please take a big heads up here:**

Placing directly the `whereClause` and `sorting` strings to your SQL query is prone to *[SQL injection](https://newbedev.com/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-with-jpa-and-hibernate)* which a malevolent user might exploit to reveal and or destroy data in your database. You should really try to use to bind the where and sort parameters rather than appending them to your SQL string, by using the `query#setParameter` method. You can read more in the link I provided about SQL injection. My example code is prone to SQL injection knowingly however I chose it for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It works exactly, how I want it. As you pointed out here, this implementation is prone to SQL Injection and I agree with you. However I tried below few  scenarios by adding delete/drop query ("name DESC, lastname ASC; Delete from foo;") in sort criteria  and it fails due to limit clause which gets appended at the end due to line  nativeQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize). Is there any scenario which I should try for sql injection?